# speed up react with typescript project build in development mode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, craco, esbuild

I have a React project using Typescript built using create react app.
The start command `react-scripts start` takes around 50s on first time and around 3 seconds on any file change.

How can I speed up the build time specially after each change in code?

Some things I already tried

1. Used craco and introduced esbuild instead of babel
2. Disabled eslint in dev mode
   But these did not gave me much improvement in speed.

In which direction I should be debugging this more?

Comment: The reddit thread [How can you speed up the slow compilation time of a CRA with Typescript template?](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/kmauu3/how_can_you_speed_up_the_slow_compilation_time_of/) suggests also disabling type checking - have you done that?

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you. I did it just now and compile time reduced to half, so around 1 seconds of compile time now. This is great.

Comment: You're welcome :) But note that you should train yourself and your google account (or whatever other search engine you use, create an account with it) so that you can get good help with programming questions: I searched for "create react app typescript slow" to find that suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if we eject the CRA and use [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) instead of Webpack makes a lot of difference in the build time. You can try that.